# Getting started with XCode and CUDA

Tags: xcode, cuda

So far I was able to install CUDA and it works fine.
However, I have no idea how to set up XCode for CUDA. And the posts out there seem to be really outdated and full of missing links and files. Also XCode seem to have changed a lot since 2009.

To begin, If I create a new project should I choose "Empty" or "External Build System" or something else?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using CMake:

1) Install latest CMake from http://www.cmake.org/download/

2) Create `CMakeLists.txt` and `main.cu`:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(cuda_test)
find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
cuda_add_executable(cuda_test main.cu)
```

**main.cu** (taken from http://thrust.github.io/)

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(32 << 20);
  std::generate(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), rand);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec = h_vec;
  thrust::sort(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end());
  thrust::copy(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), h_vec.begin());
  return 0;
}
```

3) Use CMake GUI or command line to create a Xcode project out of the above (the following uses the cmake command line)

```
cmake -G Xcode
```

Comment: Thanks man. That really helped! Could you help me and following users a little more. I updated my question.

Comment: @clankill3r you should ask a new question and close this one instead of editing your original one. Since I do not use Xcode I cannot answer anything related to it.