# Run Cuda project in XCode

Tags: xcode, cuda

I found some great tutorials about CUDA but they are for windows.

All I want is to get started a.s.a.p.

I made my project files with CMake.
If I press the play button in XCode then I can see "Build succeeded".

I added `std::cout << "Hello World!";` cause I would love to see some console output. But I don't see anything.
I did activate the console.

What are the necessary steps to make it working?

[image]

Comment: Did the build really succeed? Is there an executable created? Did you try running the program in a terminal? Can you show your CMakeLists.txt? There is a [Getting started guide for Mac OS X](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x)

Comment: @havogt My CMakeList.txt is here among the other stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938945/getting-started-with-xcode-and-cuda/31939149?noredirect=1#comment51834165_31939149

Comment: Ah thanks, there is a build! I worked with xcode for ios but that worked a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing the play button is not enough in this case.
In the Debug folder there was the build:

[image]

(to run it you can check: [Running an executable in Mac Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080835/running-an-executable-in-mac-terminal))